# Rownumber without groupby Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have three columns: id(unique), value, time

I want to create a new column that does a simple row_number without any partitioning

**I tried** : `df['test'] = df.groupby('id_col').cumcount()+1`

But the output is only ones.

**Expecting** to get 1->len of the dataframe

***Also , is there a way to do it in numpy for better performance***

Comment: `df['col1'] = np.arange(1, df.shape[0]+1)` ?

Comment: Could also use the built-in pandas index builder: `df['new_col'] = pd.RangeIndex(start=1, stop=len(df) + 1, step=1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your index is already ordered starting from 0

```
df["row_num"] = df.index + 1
```

else:

```
df["row_num"] = df.reset_index().index + 1
```

Comparing time with `%%timeit` speed from fastest to slowest: `@Scott Boston's method > @Henry Ecker's method > mine`

Answer (score 1):

```
df["row_num"] = range(1,len(df)+1)
```

Alternative:

```
df.insert(0, "row_num", range(1,len(df)+1))
```